# Is there a way to use an union in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader, union

I was wondering if there is a way to use an union in GLSL. I haven't seen any documentation about this. If not, is there a clean workaround to using a union.

I basically want an array of something. And that something might be either of 2 things, therefore I would like to use a union to define it.

Thanks!

P.S. There might be some weird casting trick to do this that I don't know about, feel free to suggest a better method.

**Edit:**

Code example(would not compile because union is not available):

```
struct A{
    bool isA;
    float value;
};
struct B{
    bool isA;
    int value;
};

/* union */
union AandB {
    A a;
    B b;
}

void main()
{
    AandB foo;
    if(foo.a.isA)
        /* process on A */

    else
        /* process on B */
}
```

Also, imagine A and B are huge, you wouldn't want to duplicate them.

**Edit 2:**

Here's some more information, hope it helps:

This data would come from "outside" and be vertex specific. It would have to be treated differently depending on the type(A or B). They'd probably be accessed from a VBO.

Comment: Can you give an example or some code of what you are attempting?

Comment: Yes, it's not valid GLSL but it's what i'm looking to do.

Comment: And where exactly does this information come from?

Comment: I made this example up, the union part would not compile for sure but the idea of what I'd like to do is there.

Comment: @user2888798: You're not quite understanding my question. Where the data comes from matters in terms of how you can actually go about doing what you're talking about. Is the data in a buffer object, accessed via UBO? Is it in an SSBO? A texture perhaps? A vertex attribute? Each of these has their own potential solutions *specific* to those data sources.

Comment: @NicolBolas They would come from "outside" and be vertex specific. The extra data would have to be treated differently depending on the type(A or B). They'd be accessed from a VBO. I hope this helps!

Comment: @user2888798: Then please put that vital information in the question, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we are talking about vertex attributes, you can do this:

```
layout(location = 0) vec4 floatVal;
layout(location = 0) ivec4 intVal;
```

OpenGL refers to this as attribute aliasing, and it is explicitly allowed, with the following caveat. Either only one of the aliased attributes is accessed, or each code path through the shader only accesses one of the attributes. So if you guard the access and value computation with a boolean condition, you'll be fine:

```
//Don't use either variable yet

if(isFloat)
{
  //Do something with `floatVal`
}
else
{
  //Do something with `intVal`
}

//Don't use either variable again.
```

Well, you'll be fine *theoretically*. Attribute aliasing is a very odd corner-case, and it's highly unlikely that any major programs that use OpenGL actually do this. Which means that implementation support will likely be buggy (code that isn't used is code that hasn't been *tested*). So I would advise you to switch programs if you want to make sure your code actually *works* across platforms.

Comment: Holy shit, this is such a hack but it's golden for what I want. Thanks a lot, sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GLSL specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf), the keyword `union` is *reserved for future use* and will indeed result in a compilation error.

One way around that would be supported by GLSL, since they encourage you to go with straightforward data structures (no evil pointer allocation or weird casting tricks), would be to use an array of struct with a flag.

```
struct AandB {
   A a;
   B b;
   bool isA;
};
```

Then, you can use it has intended with something like this:

```
AandB foo;

if (a.isA) {
   /* a process */
}
else {
   /* b process */
}
```

However, if an item has the possibility of containing neither of the types, you should be careful with the fact that the flag will be initially false and assume type B. In that case, a workaround would be to use two flags and set the correct one.

**UPDATE:**

If memory usage is an issue, there is still a way around, but it needs a funnier data structure. One way that comes in mind is having an array of item definitions that will hold an index and a flag. Let's imagine this data structure:

```
struct Item {
   bool isA;
   int index;
};

Item items[5];
A a[5];
B b[5];

Item firstAItem;
firstItem.isA = true;
firstItem.index = 0;
items[0] = firstAItem;

Item firstBItem;
firstBItem.isA = false;
firstBItem.index = 0;
items[1] = firstBItem;
```

When iterating, you could check the flag and go to the associated index, like this, assuming that `N_items` is the number of items you have:

```
for (int i=0; i<N_items; i++) {
   Item currentItem = items[i];
   if (currentItem.isA) {
      A foo = a[currentItem.index];
      /* do some stuff with foo */
   } else {
      B bar = b[currentItem.index];
      /* do some stuff with bar */
   }
}
```

Comment: Imagine A and B are huge, I would like them to share the same memory space. Would there be another clean way to do so?

Comment: See my updated answer. It is still possible to do this without intensive memory usage. Everything comes at a price of complexity, though.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, you're using the first array(items) as a "pointer" to either your 2nd or 3rd array. This would probably work if the amount of element of each type was known. (ie. I would have 9 elements of A and 1 of B, I would probably still have to declare `A a[10] ` and `B b[10]` just in case). This would take double the memory. I could maybe make this work but I'm really looking for a way to share the same memory space, if that's possible...

Comment: You can still keep the count of how many items of each type you insert. It would be more simple to share the same memory space, but I don't think it is possible without `union` or pointers which are not supported.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as the best one if there isn't anyone with a better solution